# Flex & Visual Studio Development Environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, apache-flex, flexbuilder

My development team have a requirment to add Adobe Flex (Chart Animation) to their .NET 4 MVC 2 (Visual Studio 2010) application and I'm trying to work out the actual development environment requirements for this. My main question is around Adobe Flex/Flash Builder?

Correct me if I wrong, but here is what I think we need:

- All MSFT Dev Tools (Visual Studio 2010 SP1)
- Flex SDK
- [Ensemble Tofino](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_tofino_visualstudio.html) for Visual Studio and Flex IDE Integration
- Adobe Flex/Flash Builder? (Do I need this?)

Can anyone else see anything I might be missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer in the FAQ

Can I build and deploy Flex applications for free?
Yes. There are no deployment licensing costs associated with Flex. Using only the free Flex SDK, you can build and deploy Flex applications for free. For a more productive development experience, you may also want to use Flash Builder 4.6, which is available starting at US$249. You can try Flash Builder 4.6 Premium for 60 days at no charge. Using open source BlazeDS, you can leverage high-speed, binary data transfer and real-time data push.

Comment: I believe the Flex Data Visualization SDK components require a licensed version of the Flex SDK.  Historically I recall only compiled SWC were available for data visualization components, and purchase was required for source.